# maxscale read/write split with MYSQL master/slave

Tags: mysql, load-balancing

I am setting up mysql MMM with two slaves. I will used slaves for read only and master for writes only. I do not have read/write split in application.
I came across maxscale program. I was wondering if it will do read/write split for me in my scenario.
Thanks

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more db/server configuration. Try the DBA site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MaxScale can be used to automatically split read and write queries, without changing the application. It will redirect reads that are not in transactional context (e.g. reads in autocommit mode) to the slaves.